# Soft terminating a simple webserver

Tags: c, sockets, webserver

I'm building my own webserver. For now, my minimalist code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 80

int main () {

    int nReqSocketId, nReqSize = 1024, nMainSocketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    char *sRequest = malloc(nReqSize);
    socklen_t nAddrLen;
    struct sockaddr_in oAddress;

    oAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    oAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    oAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if (nMainSocketId == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during the creation of the socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, sizeof(oAddress))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The port %d is busy\n", SERVER_PORT);
        close(nMainSocketId);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("HTTP server listening on port %d\n", SERVER_PORT);

    while (1) {

        if (listen(nMainSocketId, 10) < 0) {
            perror("server: listen");
            close(nMainSocketId);
            exit(1);
        }

        nReqSocketId = accept(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, &nAddrLen);

        if (nReqSocketId < 0) {
            perror("server: accept");
            close(nMainSocketId);
            exit(1);
        }

        recv(nReqSocketId, sRequest, nReqSize, 0);

        if (nReqSocketId > 0){
            printf("The Client is connected...\n\n%s\n", sRequest);
        }

        write(nReqSocketId, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
        write(nReqSocketId, "Content-length: 50\n", 19);
        write(nReqSocketId, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
        write(nReqSocketId, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n", 50);
        close(nReqSocketId);

    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");

    close(nMainSocketId);

    return 0;

}
```

Can I create a "soft closing mechanism" making the webserver to print the "Goodbye!" phrase located after the infinite loop? When I type the "q" letter, for example…

Comment: To you want to soft-terminate it from the server's terminal window, or from a client request? (or both?) The former highly OS-specific because you can't wait on terminals the same way on *n*x and Windows. The latter is as easy as parsing a HTTP request.

Comment: Ctrl + C and handler of SIGINT.

Comment: @Medinoc I'd like to soft-terminate it from my linux server's terminal window!

Comment: @someuser Ctrl + C kills the process BEFORE the line printf("Goodbye!\n");

Comment: @user2732907 That's why Medinoc said "_and handler of SIGINT_". Install a signal handler for the SIGINT that sets a volatile integer to zero, and let that volatile integer be the control expression for your loop.

Comment: @user2732907 Also you can move `printf("Goodbye!\n");` into a signal handler.If you need a **printing "bye-bye" before exit** and not a **printing after loop exactly**.

Comment: @user2732907 If you want a first variant then yoy also can use two processes: child - server, parent - controlling with menu "Start/Stop/bla-bla-bla". But I like signals more.

Comment: @someuser: Calling `printf()` from a signal handler is strongly disadvised as **only** async-signal-safe functions shall be called from signal handlers and the whole family of `*printf*()` functions is **not guaranteed** to be signal safe. For list of function guarantted to be signal-safe please see down under 2.4.2: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04

Comment: @alk printf() is only a debug test for now: my intention is to put some free() and regfree() functions within the signal handler.

Comment: @user2732907: None of such functions a guaranteed to be async-signal-save, as you might already know having taken a look at the list I linked in my previous command.

Answer (score 1):

Why not eliminate all of those write functions and just use a single send()?

All you would need to do is store your response in a buffer, then send buffer:

```
// Global
#define MAX 2048
char response[MAX]; // No need for char* 

// In Main
memset(response, 0, MAX); // **EDIT**
strcpy(response, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
strcat(response, "Content-length: 50\n");
strcat(response, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
strcat(response, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n");

// Now simply send the whole response in one go:
send(nReqSocketId, response, strlen(response), 0);
```

Also, you could also simply make this a non persistent connection like so:

```
// Global
#define MAX 2048
char response[MAX];  // No need for char* 

// In Main
memset(response, 0, MAX); // **EDIT**
strcpy(response, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
strcat(response, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
strcat(response, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n");

// Now simply send the whole response in one go again:
send(nReqSocketId, response, strlen(response), 0);

// Shutdown the socket so it cannot write anymore:
shutdown(nReqSocketId,1);

// Then totally close it when you are ready:
close(nReqSocketId);
```

The latter might be better suited for what you are currently doing; since you are not keeping multiple connections alive in your webserver anyways.

Once you close down a connection on the server side the client (i.e. the web browser) knows to stop expecting content and will finish the job properly.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

PS-

This, of course, a response to your last question in this thread not so much the soft-termination part.

I would also have to suggest that you memset(response, 0, MAX) so that you have a nice clean slate every time you are responding.

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestions of @Medinoc, @someuser and @Elchonon I corrected my code in the following way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 80

int nStatus, nMainSocketId;

void onInt () {
    printf("You have pressed CTRL-C.\n");
    nStatus = 0;
    shutdown(nMainSocketId, 2);
}

void onQuit () {
    printf("You have pressed CTRL-\\.\n");
    nStatus = 0;
    shutdown(nMainSocketId, 2);
}

int main () {

    int nReqSocketId, nReqSize = 1024;
    nMainSocketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    char *sRequest = malloc(nReqSize);
    socklen_t nAddrLen;
    struct sockaddr_in oAddress;

    signal(SIGINT, onInt);
    signal(SIGQUIT, onQuit);
    oAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    oAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    oAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    nStatus = 1;

    printf("\n  W E L C O M E!\n\nPress CTRL-C or CTRL-\\ to quit.\n");

    if (nMainSocketId == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during the creation of the socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, sizeof(oAddress))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The port %d is busy\n", SERVER_PORT);
        close(nMainSocketId);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("HTTP server listening on port %d\n", SERVER_PORT);

    while (nStatus) {

        if (listen(nMainSocketId, 10) < 0) {
            perror("server: listen");
            close(nMainSocketId);
            return 1;
        }

        nReqSocketId = accept(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, &nAddrLen);

        if (nReqSocketId < 0) {
            perror("server: accept");
            close(nMainSocketId);
            return 1;
        }

        recv(nReqSocketId, sRequest, nReqSize, 0);

        if (nReqSocketId > 0){
            printf("The Client is connected...\n\n%s\n", sRequest);
        }

        write(nReqSocketId, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
        write(nReqSocketId, "Content-length: 50\n", 19);
        write(nReqSocketId, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
        write(nReqSocketId, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n", 50);
        close(nReqSocketId);

    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");

    close(nMainSocketId);

    return 0;

}
```

The process sof-terminates, now!! But, unfortunately, the socket no! :( …so I get the following message whenever I press CTRL-C or CTRL-\ in order to quit:

```
server: accept: Invalid argument
```

Any suggestion to fix it?

**EDIT**

@alk

Thank you for your answer! You suggested me an alternative way to soft-terminate my webserver...:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 80

int bExiting, nMainSocketId;

void terminateServer () {
    if (bExiting) { return; }
    printf("\n\nTerminating server...\n");
    close(nMainSocketId);
    bExiting = 1;
}

int main () {

    int nRecvResult = -1, nReqSocketId = -1;
    size_t nReqSize = 1024;
    char * sRequest = malloc(nReqSize);
    socklen_t nAddrLen;
    struct sockaddr_in oAddress = {0};

    printf("\n  W E L C O M E!\n\nPress CTRL-C or CTRL-\\ to quit.\n");

    signal(SIGINT, terminateServer);
    signal(SIGQUIT, terminateServer);

    oAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    oAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    oAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    nMainSocketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (nMainSocketId < 0) {
        perror("server: socket() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, sizeof(oAddress))) {
        perror("server: bind() failed");
        terminateServer();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("HTTP server listening on port %d\n", SERVER_PORT);

    while (bExiting == 0) {

        if (listen(nMainSocketId, 10) < 0) {
            perror("server: listen() failed");
            terminateServer();
            return 1;
        }

        nReqSocketId = accept(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, &nAddrLen);

        if (bExiting) { break; }

        if (nReqSocketId < 0) {
            perror("server: accept failed()");
            terminateServer();
            return 1;
        }

        nRecvResult = recv(nReqSocketId, sRequest, nReqSize, 0);

        if (nRecvResult < 0) {
            perror("server: recv() failed");
            terminateServer();
            return 1;
        }

        if (nRecvResult == 0) {
            printf("The client is disconnected. Waiting for another connection...\n");
            close(nReqSocketId);
            continue;
        }

        printf("The client is connected...\n\n%s\n", sRequest);

        /* This is only a simple "Hello world"... */
        write(nReqSocketId, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
        write(nReqSocketId, "Content-length: 50\n", 19);
        write(nReqSocketId, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
        write(nReqSocketId, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n", 50);

        close(nReqSocketId);

    }

    free(sRequest);
    printf("Goodbye!\n");

    return 0;

}
```

What do you think about it? Should I add something?

Still, I have yet another question. Can I can use fprintf() in conjunction with a file descriptor as alternative to write()? And... how?

Comment: Which OS are you planning to run this on?

Answer (score 0):

Under an *IXish OS a signal will wake up certain blocking system calls and have them return.

They will indicate an eror and set `errno` to `EINTR`. Such mechanics you can use to gracefully shutdown your server.

Please see code from your answer slightly adjusted/corrected below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 8080 /* Using a port>1024 one does not need to run this as root. */

void onInt()
{
  /* Do nothing. */
}

void onQuit()
{
  /* Do nothing. */
}

int main()
{
  int nMainSocketId = -1, nReqSocketId = -1;
  size_t nReqSize = 1024;
  char * sRequest = malloc(nReqSize); /* TODO: add error checking */
  socklen_t nAddrLen;
  struct sockaddr_in oAddress = {0};

  signal(SIGINT, onInt); /* TODO: add error checking */
  signal(SIGQUIT, onQuit); /* TODO: add error checking */

  printf("\n  W E L C O M E!\n\nPress CTRL-C or CTRL-\\ to quit.\n");

  oAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
  oAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  oAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

  nMainSocketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (nMainSocketId < 0) /* 0 is a valid file/socket descriptor! */
  {
    perror("server: socket() failed");
    return 1;
  }

  if (bind(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, sizeof(oAddress)))
  {
    perror("server: bind() failed");
    close(nMainSocketId);
    return 1;
  }

  printf("HTTP server listening on port %d\n", SERVER_PORT);

  while (1)
  {
    int result = 0;

    if (listen(nMainSocketId, 10) < 0)
    {
      perror("server: listen() failed");
      close(nMainSocketId);
      return 1;
    }

    result = accept(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, &nAddrLen);
    if (result < 0)
    {
      if (EINTR == errno)
      {
        printf("Shutdown requested. Exiting ...\n");
        break;
      }

      perror("server: accept failed()");
      close(nMainSocketId);
      return 1;
    }

    nReqSocketId = result;

    result = recv(nReqSocketId, sRequest, nReqSize, 0); /* TODO: Check wether the request size was really read! */
    if (result < 0)
    {
      perror("server: recv() failed");
      close(nMainSocketId);
      return 1;
    }
    else if (result == 0)
    {
      printf("The client is disconnected. Waiting for another connection ...\n");
      close(nReqSocketId);
      nReqSocketId = -1;
      continue;
    }

    printf("The client is connected...\n\n%s\n", sRequest);

    /* TODO: add error checking for ALL write()s */
    write(nReqSocketId, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
    write(nReqSocketId, "Content-length: 50\n", 19);
    write(nReqSocketId, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
    write(nReqSocketId, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n", 50);

    close(nReqSocketId);
    nReqSocketId = -1;
  }

  printf("Goodbye!\n");

  close(nMainSocketId);

  return 0;
}
```

Be aware that also the call to `recv()` could block waiting for data and then due to `SIGINT` be interupted. So the same logic as done when checking the result of `accept()` should be applied to `recv()`.

Answer (score 0):

@PandaSobao

I removed write() using fprintf() in conjunction with a file descriptor, I think this is the best way, because doesn't require strlen()... Look at the code below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define REQUEST_SIZE 1024
#define SERVER_PORT 80

int bExiting, nMainSocketId;

void terminateServer () {
    if (bExiting) { return; }
    printf("\n\nTerminating server...\n");
    close(nMainSocketId);
    bExiting = 1;
}

int main () {

    int nRecvResult = -1, nReqSocketId = -1;
    char sRequest[REQUEST_SIZE];
    socklen_t nAddrLen;
    struct sockaddr_in oAddress;
    FILE *nRespFD;

    printf("\n  W E L C O M E!\n\nPress CTRL-C or CTRL-\\ to quit.\n");

    signal(SIGINT, terminateServer);
    signal(SIGQUIT, terminateServer);

    oAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    oAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    oAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    nMainSocketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (nMainSocketId < 0) {
        perror("server: socket() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, sizeof(oAddress))) {
        perror("server: bind() failed");
        terminateServer();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("HTTP server listening on port %d\n", SERVER_PORT);

    while (bExiting == 0) {

        if (listen(nMainSocketId, 10) < 0) {
            perror("server: listen() failed");
            terminateServer();
            return 1;
        }

        nReqSocketId = accept(nMainSocketId, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, &nAddrLen);

        if (bExiting) { break; }

        if (nReqSocketId < 0) {
            perror("server: accept() failed");
            terminateServer();
            return 1;
        }

        nRecvResult = recv(nReqSocketId, sRequest, REQUEST_SIZE, 0);

        if (nRecvResult < 0) {
            perror("server: recv() failed");
            terminateServer();
            return 1;
        }

        if (nRecvResult == 0) {
            printf("The client is disconnected. Waiting for another connection...\n");
            close(nReqSocketId);
            continue;
        }

        printf("The client is connected...\n\n%s\n", sRequest);

        nRespFD = fdopen(nReqSocketId, "a+");

        fprintf(nRespFD, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
        fprintf(nRespFD, "Content-length: 50\n");
        fprintf(nRespFD, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
        fprintf(nRespFD, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n");

        fclose(nRespFD);

        close(nReqSocketId);

    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");

    return 0;

}
```

About shutdown() versus close(), could you explain better the difference?

Comment: shutdown() can block only sending, only receiving, etc. but doesn't actually close the socket, so its descriptor is still valid. **NOTE:** When I first posted, I wasn't thinking interrupts, I was thinking `select`. On *n*x, you can use it on `STDIN_FILENO`, so you can wait simultaneously on the terminal and the socket. With this, you can even do a full-on command-line interpreter for your server (allowing you to do various things such as kicking users) instead of merely exiting!

Comment: @Medinoc
Thank you for your explanation!
About STDIN_FILENO, waiting simultaneously on the terminal and the socket is what I would like to do!!! Can you send a minimal working example?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the second part of my response explains how to make your web server non-persistent. Persistent-Connections used to be known as Keep-Alive prior to HTTP 1.1, btw.  Since I saw that you are closing your response socket every time after you send you might as well make the web server 'non-persistent.'

This means you do not have to send "Content-Length: X" because of shutdown().  You can shutdown a socket three different ways:

```
"The constants SHUT_RD, SHUT_WR, SHUT_RDWR have the value 0, 1, 2, respectively..."
```

By doing shutdown(SOCKET, 1) we are essentially sending a FIN ack to the client (browser) that lets it know that the socket is done writing.  Therefore, no need to set a "Content-Length: X"  header response.

Now, this is not a shutdown() VS close() thing.  It is a shutdown() AND close() thing.  You still have to close() the socket in order to destroy it.  Shutdown does not do that for you.

In summary, if you have no need to keep track of multiple connections consider taking out "Content-Length:" from header. Just use shutdown(SOCKET, 1) as an "end of transmission" mechanism and close to destroy the socket afterwards.

/----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

As far as creating a whole FILE* just to send string literals, I am not sure is worth it.  Have you benched this and gotten some results?  Regardless, I know of other ways around strcat() [ which includes a strlen() of course] and strlen() all together if performance is what you are looking for.  I was not aware that was the case.

PS- strcat() is pretty fast in the beginning, only when concatenating a large buffer does it start to increase its complexity.  Look up SIMD and how some those types of functions are optimized depending on your architecture.

Comment: Thank for your explanation about shutdown().
About fprintf() + FILE*… I don't know if it is faster than send() + strlen(): I have only seen that fprintf() + FILE* is often used in some didactic webserver examples…

Answer (score 0):

**Waiting on both stdin and the socket**

This is a POSIX-specific behavior that explicitly doesn't work on Windows. It relies on the fact that on *n*x platforms, sockets are file descriptors, and it uses the `select` function.

Here is a simplified function that wraps `select` to wait on a single socket.

```
/*Waits on a single socket and stdin.*/
int waitOnStdinAndSocket(
 int sockFd,             /*[in] Socket descriptor*/
 int *pInputOnStdin,     /*[out] Set to a nonzero value if there is input on stdin*/
 int *pInputOnSocket,    /*[out] Set to a nonzero value if there is input on the socket*/
 sturct timeval *timeout /*[in/opt] Timeout*/
 ) /*Returns a negative value on failure.*/
{
    int ret;
    fd_set fds;

    *pInputOnStdin = 0;
    *pInputOnSocket = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
    FD_SET(sockFd, &fds);
    ret = select(sockFd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, timeout);
    if(ret >= 0)
    {
        *pInputOnStdin = FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
        *pInputOnSocket = FD_ISSET(sockFd, &fds);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Medinoc

Thank you very much!

After reading your reply I have tried a bit 'on the net and have found this GNU page: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html.

So, after some attempts, I have been able to integrate all things with my "hello world" example. And here is the result:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 80
#define REQUEST_MAX_SIZE 1024

char sRequest[REQUEST_MAX_SIZE];
int bListening = 1, nMainSocket;

void terminateServer () {
    if (bListening == 0) { return; }
    printf("\n\nTerminating server...\n");
    close(nMainSocket);
    bListening = 0;
}

void switchStdin () {
    if (strcmp(sRequest, "q\n") == 0) {
        terminateServer();
    } else {
        printf("Unknown request %s\n", sRequest);
    }
}

void helloWorld (const int nRequestId) {
    printf("The client is connected...\n\n%s\n", sRequest);
        write(nRequestId, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
        write(nRequestId, "Content-length: 50\n", 19);
        write(nRequestId, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
        write(nRequestId, "<html><body><h1>Hello world!!!</h1></body></html>\n", 50);
}

int main (void) {

    int nOldReqSock, nNewReqSock, nReqLen, nUninitLen = REQUEST_MAX_SIZE;
    fd_set oActiveFD, oReadFD;
    socklen_t nAddrLen;
    struct sockaddr_in oAddress;

    oAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    oAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    oAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /* Create the socket and set it up to accept connections. */

    nMainSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (nMainSocket < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(nMainSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, sizeof(oAddress))) {
        perror("bind");
        terminateServer();
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(nMainSocket, 10) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        terminateServer();
        return 1;
    }

    /* Initialize the set of active sockets plus STDIN. */

    FD_ZERO(&oActiveFD);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &oActiveFD);
    FD_SET(nMainSocket, &oActiveFD);

    printf("\n  W E L C O M E!\n\nType \"q\" to quit.\n");

    while (bListening) {

        /* Block until input arrives on one or more active sockets. */

        oReadFD = oActiveFD;

        if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &oReadFD, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            perror("select");
            terminateServer();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        /* Service all the sockets with input pending. */

        for (nOldReqSock = 0; bListening && nOldReqSock < FD_SETSIZE; ++nOldReqSock) {

            if (FD_ISSET(nOldReqSock, &oReadFD)) {

                if (nOldReqSock == nMainSocket) {

                    /* Connection request on original socket. */

                    nAddrLen = sizeof(oAddress); /* why??? */
                    nNewReqSock = accept(nMainSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &oAddress, &nAddrLen);

                    if (nNewReqSock < 0) {
                        perror("accept");
                        terminateServer();
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }

                    FD_SET(nNewReqSock, &oActiveFD);

                } else {

                    /* Data arriving on an already-connected socket. */

                    nReqLen = read(nOldReqSock, sRequest, REQUEST_MAX_SIZE);

                    if (nReqLen < 0) {
                        /* Read error. */
                        perror("read");
                        terminateServer();
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    } else if (nReqLen == 0) {
                        /* End-of-file. */
                        printf("End-of-file\n");
                        close(nOldReqSock); /* why??? */
                        FD_CLR(nOldReqSock, &oActiveFD); /* why??? */
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        /* Data read. */
                        if (nUninitLen > nReqLen) { memset(sRequest + nReqLen, 0, nUninitLen - nReqLen); }
                        nUninitLen = nReqLen;
                    }

                    if (nOldReqSock == STDIN_FILENO) {
                        /* Standard input received */
                        switchStdin(nReqLen);
                    } else {
                        /* TCP/IP request received */
                        helloWorld(nOldReqSock);
                    }

                }

            } 

        }

    }

    printf("Goodbye\n");

    return 0;

}
```

I added also some `/* why??? */` comments near the lines that I do not understand. Could I ask you to explain in short what are they?